# Inserting default value as current date + 30 days in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I make a column's default value equal to the current date + 30 days in MySQL? For example, if current date is 10-1-2011 then the column value must be inserted as 9-2-2011.

Comment: Accept some previous answers, you'll earn reputation and get better answers in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using MySQL >= 5.0, use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setDefaultDate
    BEFORE INSERT ON tableName
    FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.date = ADDDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

The [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) will activate when you insert into `tableName`, setting `date` to now + 30 days. If your insert sets the date, it will override this default due to the `BEFORE`. The date is calculated using [`ADDDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate).