# MySQL - Default Timestamp of n days in the future

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to set a fields default timestamp to n days in the future. For example I can setup a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
     name varchar(64),
     ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I would want that whenever ts is not indicated that it would set the default value for n days in the future. I've seen here that it can be done via triggers ([Inserting default value as current date + 30 days in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614332/inserting-default-value-as-current-date-30-days-in-mysql)), but is there any other way of doing this without triggers?

Comment: I would suggest that having the default value n days in the future is application business logic and doesn't really belong in database table definitions.

Comment: I dont think you can set the default to a feature date as of now. It has to be by some other way like trigger.

Comment: Can't be done with `DEFAULT` in MySQL.  Per the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html), `DEFAULT` requires that the value be static, with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` being the sole exception.  It can't be any other function or expression.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I'll use the trigger then. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Another option is to create a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)  (see: answer by @matt-saunders)

Answer (score 4):

This is (now?) possible. To add a column `ts` to table `t1` with a default of the current date / time plus 30 days, use:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD ts DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Tested with MySQL 8.0.23.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html) (and like @bacon-bits wrote), this is not currently possible. `DEFAULT` must be a static value, with the exception of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.