# how to make an expiration date for an inserted row

Tags: laravel-8

I want an inserted row to appear in another section after a period of time that I set.
I'm working on a web application I created a form where I insert a product information and I have created a table to show the data from database. I want to set a timer for the inserted columns after that time expired data should be shown in another table.

Is it possible to be done in Laravel 8?

Comment: Not laravel-specific, bur you could have a table column with a default value of (current  + x days) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614332/inserting-default-value-as-current-date-30-days-in-mysql

Comment: I mean after the insertion ,when 10 seconds passes i want data to appear in another section

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific with how you want the information to appear? Do you have an extra column with the date when you want to display the record? Or are you going to measure the time statically with a database query?

Comment: i want that record to appear in another section named expired products for example, after some time passes